# Identifying public and confidential clients for Oauth2.0

Tags: php, .net, oauth-2.0, backend, openid-connect

I have a problem identifying the type of the app based just on the programming language.

In case of an application with separated backend and frontend, but the frontend developed with a backend language (Java, .Net, PHP) , could we understand that the frontend is a confidential client ?

I know that we also have mobile apps developed with backend language (.net for exmple) so I am a bit confused.

Thank you very much for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Applications running on the user's machine (mobile/desktop/browsers) typically can't keep any secrets (keys/passwords...), and because of that, they are all public clients.

The programming language used does not affect this at all.